# oracle disconnect behaviour

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What will happen if connection is lost during long operation?

For example there is a select statement that takes several minutes to complete and connection is lost during its execution. Will it continue execution or will be stopped?

For a delete statement: will it be executed to its finish or interrupted when client disconnects? What will happen to the data: will it be committed or rolled back, how soon?

For a ddl operation: I have a long running `alter table tbl_name move` operation, what will happen to it when client loses connection? Will continue execution or will be interrupted?

Comment: Read [`ACID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties. It says "All or nothing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that we're talking about something akin to the client application crashing or the network connection getting dropped rather than a situation where the application is doing a clean disconnect since you cannot do a clean disconnect while a transaction is open let alone while a statement is running.

In general, the statement will run to completion on the server (where "completion" for a `SELECT` is the point at which it can return the first set of rows the client requested which may or may not require executing the statement in its entirety).  The server will then attempt to communicate the fact that the result is ready back to the client.  When it doesn't get a response back (it may take a few minutes to time out waiting for the `ACK` packet), it knows that the client process is dead and begins the process of rolling back the uncommitted transaction (which releases all the locks held by the transaction).  If you have made changes to the database as part of your transaction (i.e. you have done inserts, updates, and/or deletes), it can take as long to roll back the changes as it took to generate the changes in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

For simple DML statements like your `select` and `delete`, the transaction will either be rolled back or committed.

**"When" will this occur?**  It doesn't actually matter.  Other clients only see the result of committed transactions, so the timing is irrelevant.

For DDL statements, according to [the official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/sqllangu.htm), "An implicit COMMIT occurs immediately before the database executes a DDL statement and a COMMIT or ROLLBACK occurs immediately afterward".

Within a transaction, if you were to do some DML statements, and then a DDL statement, the DML statements could be committed, yet the DDL statement rolled back - even though they were all in the same transaction.

For the simple examples you gave though, it's all or nothing.  ...and in general, if you lose your connection before receiving confirmation of a committed transaction - you just won't whether it worked or not.  You'll have to verify.

[**EDIT**: just to elaborate slightly on *"you have to verify"*...you have to verify if you've sent the database a "commit" (explicitly or implicitly), and you lose your connection before you know whether the database performed the commit.
If you lose your connection before issuing a commit, you can be guaranteed it will be rolled back (with the DDL caveat above)]

Comment: The "when" may matter when a long-running `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement will acquire locks that need to be released by rolling back the transaction.  It won't matter to queries because of the multi-version read consistency that you're talking about.  But it will matter if someone needs to restart that long-running operation in another session.

Answer (score 0):

all database operations are works according to `ACID` properties.

```
Atomicity
```

All changes to data are performed as if they are a single operation. That is, all the changes are performed, or none of them are.
 that means according to Atomicity, changes are rollbacked.

Comment: The trickier part is the "when". It seems that Oracle is not exactly fast at picking up that the connection is down.