# How does Oracle handle SQL when autocommit=false and there is no commit or rollback?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, commit, rollback

I am running Java and Oracle SQL 11g.

What happens if you establish a connection to a database, setting the connection to AutoCommit=False but you have neither a commit() nor a rollback() ?

I have my code wrapped in a try/catch/finally and in the finally I have a rollback.  However, I noticed that I am missing two records from a table.  My assumption is that I was in my code in debug mode and clicked the stop button so it didnt reach the rollback command, nor does it have a commit anywhere in between.

Comment: isn't the `finally` block supposed to be executed _always_?  if so, you're always rolling back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have neither a commit nor a rollback, the transaction would remain open waiting for you to issue one or the other.  If you tried to [close the Connection object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) the results are implementation-dependent.  Your transaction might be committed, it might be rolled back.

Comment: With respect to Oracle specifically, you have already answered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865262/oracle-disconnect-behaviour and as someone else pointed out in another response there are implicit commits before certain commands. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/sqllangu.htm#CHDHBIGA